# D3.js - adding of new elements to a 2d-array doesn't result in new dom (svg) elements

Tags: d3.js

I'm just learning d3.js and want to visualize my data in a 2d grid of colored rectangles. The d3 code below gets called whenever my data changes. It properly builds the initial grid, updates existing cells correctly, and reacts to removal of existing items as intended (cells get removed + others updated).

However, when I add a (new) data item, the grid data gets updated correctly but no new cells will be added - which means that the last element in the grid won't be displayed.

From my very basic d3.js understanding, the difference in size between the existing data and the new data should result in a non-empty "*squares.enter()*" selection in the enter block such that a new **rect** element should get added to the last row.

Could anyone tell me how my assumption is wrong? or give me a hint what I have to change to add new data?

```
//format 1d to 2d array
let d = this.gridData(this.props.data);

//Enter rows
let rows = d3
  .select(this.svgRef.current)
  .selectAll(".row")
  .data(d)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "row");

//Enter cells for each row
let squares = rows.selectAll(".square").data(d => d);
squares.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "square")
  .attr("x", d => d.x)
  .attr("y", d => d.y)
  .attr("width", d => d.width)
  .attr("height", d => d.height)
  .style("fill", d => d.c)
  .style("stroke", d => {
    if (d.id == this.props.focus) {
      return "#FF0000";
    } else {
      return "#FFFFFF";
    }
  });

//Update cells
squares = d3.select(this.svgRef.current).selectAll(".row")

squares.selectAll(".square")
  .attr("x", d => d.x)
  .attr("y", d => d.y)
  .attr("width", d => d.width)
  .attr("height", d => d.height)
  .style("fill", d => d.c)
  .style("stroke", d => {
    if (d.id == this.props.focus) {
      return "#FF0000";
    } else {
      return "#FFFFFF";
    }
  });

//exit => remove rows/cells
squares.exit().remove();
squares.selectAll(".square").data(d => d).exit().remove();
```

Comment: you don't add a new row `g` on update

Comment: @rioV8 Ty for your input but I'm not quite sure if I understand what you mean. Why do I need to add a new container? On an update the number of cells (and containers/rows) stays the same. 

How does it relate to my problem of adding new elements?

Comment: why do you add a new `g` for each row? Why do you bind `data` on update if the number of cells do not change?

Comment: You are correct. I don't need to rebind the data on an update. I add a `g` for each row for the line breaks. I can now see how that adds another layer of complexity that I can remove.

However I don't see how this solves the problem of cells not getting created for new elements. I'll refactor though

Comment: you say the number of cells stay the same, so there is nothing to add. Why do you have code duplication in create and update of cells.

Comment: In my test I have initially 56 elements that are organized in a 2d array => d is an array of 5 length 10 + 1 length 6 arrays. This translates to 6 `p` containers where 5 have 10 `rect` and the last one has 6 `rect` elements.

Whe I delete an element the last array in d has only 5 elements. Consequently a `rect`element in the last `p` container gets removed.

When I addd an element d has the right shape again. However, no `rect`element gets created. Thats my problem.

I have some code duplication because the style might change on the update - and it didn't work without duplication

Comment: where in the `update` do you create new cells? ever considered using `selection.call` to update the attributes and remove code duplication. Best to put this whole create/update in one function.

Comment: I (should) create a new cells in the _enter_ section right after I bind the data -  `squares.enter().append("rect")`

I don't know `selection.call` yet but i'll look it up tomorro ty.

Comment: Can you create a working example with data (you can use the Stack Snippets function to do so) and specify which version of d3 you are using?